# Symfony2 Class redeclaration after form_login

Tags: php, symfony

Okay, I have been stuck on this for a couple of days and can't find an answer. I have been trying to learn how to use Symfony 2 a I built a little CMS application following a tutorial. Now I am trying to build a task manager application just by myself for practice but I keep running into a class re-declaration error. The interesting part is it works fine until I change my security.yml to add form_login. Once I add that I get an error about re-declaring my password encoder class and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    namespace\taskBundle\Entity\User:
        id: namespace.task.salt_peanuts_encoder
providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [in_memory, user_db]
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                admin:: {password: temppass, roles: ROLE_ADMIN}
    user_db:
        entity: { class: taskBundle:User, property:username }
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    secured_areas:
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /
```

Password encoder:

```
namespace namespace\taskBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class saltPeanutEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface {

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
        return password_hash($salt . "placeholder" . $raw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) {
        return $this->encodePassword($raw, $salt) === $encoded;
    }

}
```

Here is my services.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services       http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="namespace.task.salt_peanuts_encoder" class="namespace\taskBundle\Service\saltPeanutsEncoder">
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Se here is the page without form_login declared in security.yml
[image: Without form_login]

And here it is with form_login added into security.yml.

[image: with form_login]

I have tried adding the form_login in different places in the security.yml, under default and creating a main section and then lastly trying the secured_areas. I cannot find what is causing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I know namespace is a reserved word in php I replaced the actual namespace with the word namespace for anonymity reasons.

Comment: Maybe I will be downwoted but have you tried clearing cache? Have you tried searching yor project files for case insensitive `saltPeanutEncoder`?

Comment: I haven't tried clearing that cache. I am new to Symfony2 and was under the impression that if you are on localhost (I am actually using the built in server) that that was already taken care of (not that there are some exceptions). I will give it a shot and see what happens.

Comment: @piotrekkr well clearing the cache didn't solve the issue but it told me where the issue was. There was a mismatch in the name of the file for the encoder vs the class name of the encoder. Thank you for your help

Comment: I hate bugs like that, they are really easy to miss. Your error message screenshot shows that you missed `s` in your class name. Am I correct?

Comment: That is correct. It threw me off cause the error said i was re-declaring the class so somehow i thought it was getting loaded twice.